# Importing Google Drive Quickstart Code to Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I am trying to get the Quickstart code for .Net imported to Visual Basic (VB .NET) and I had some errors. I am a newbie to this kind of programming. Would appreciate some pointers, or someone pointing out something that is fundamentally wrong with the code.

Appreciate the help!

The errors that I get when I try to compile the Console App are:

> Error 2   Argument not specified for parameter 'arg' of 'Private Shared Function GetAuthorization(arg As Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient) As DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState'. C:\Documents and Settings\Hirak\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\Nipod Drive Console\Module1.vb   22  86  Nipod Drive Console
>
> Error  3   'BaseClientService' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Google.Apis.Services'.   C:\Documents and Settings\Hirak\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\Nipod Drive Console\Module1.vb   23  48  Nipod Drive Console

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Util
Imports Google.Apis.Services

Namespace GoogleDriveSamples

Class DriveCommandLineSample

    Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String)

        Dim CLIENT_ID As [String] = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
        Dim CLIENT_SECRET As [String] = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"

        '' Register the authenticator and create the service
        Dim provider = New    NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, GetAuthorization)
        Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
 .Authenticator = auth _
})

        Dim body As New File()
        body.Title = "My document"
        body.Description = "A test document"
        body.MimeType = "text/plain"

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt")
        Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)

        Dim request As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain")
        request.Upload()

        Dim file As File = request.ResponseBody
        Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id)
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub



    Private Shared Function GetAuthorization(ByVal arg As NativeApplicationClient) As IAuthorizationState

        ' Get the auth URL:
        Dim state As IAuthorizationState = New AuthorizationState( New () {DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue()})

        state.Callback = New Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
        Dim authUri As Uri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state)

        ' Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString())
        Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ")
        Dim authCode As String = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine()

        ' Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        Return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state)

    End Function

End Class


End Namespace
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the error related to `BaseClientService` but for the error around `arg` (Error 2) I think it is because this: `Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, GetAuthorization)` should be something like this: `Dim auth = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, AddressOf GetAuthorization)` instead

Comment: @nkvu Thanks! It was expecting 'AddressOf' and that change did care of that error.

Comment: the Base Client was due to the Silverlight .dll library being added to the project as well. It does not need to be there. I took that out and this error has gone.

Comment: Changing the state definition thus `Dim state As IAuthorizationState = New AuthorizationState(New DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationState With {.AccessToken = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue()})` got rid of the compile error. But, got a runtime error at `request.upload()` as **Unable to cast object of type 'DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationState' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.**

Answer (score 0):

I reliase this is an old subject, but this may help someone in future, make sure you compile in framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cant seem to edit or delete my previous answer, for anyone in future, this should help:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Util
Imports System.Security
Imports Google.Apis.Services


Public Class GoogleDrive
    Public Function UploadFile() As Boolean
        Const CLIENT_ID As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        Const CLIENT_SECRET As String = "-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

        'Register the authenticator and create the service
        Dim provider As NativeApplicationClient = New NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        Dim getAuth As Func(Of NativeApplicationClient, IAuthorizationState) = AddressOf GetAuthorization
        Dim auth As OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient) = New OAuth2Authenticator(Of NativeApplicationClient)(provider, getAuth)
        Dim service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.Authenticator = auth})

        Dim body As File = New File()
        body.Title = "My document"
        body.Description = "A test document"
        body.MimeType = "text/plain"

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\document.txt")
        Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)

        Dim request As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain")
        request.Upload()
        Dim file As File = request.ResponseBody
        MessageBox.Show("File : " & file.Id)
    End Function

    Private Function GetAuthorization(ByVal Client As NativeApplicationClient) As IAuthorizationState

        Dim RetVal As IAuthorizationState
        Dim state As IAuthorizationState = New AuthorizationState(New String() {DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue()})

        'Check to see if we have a saved refresh token
        If My.Settings.SavedAuth.ToString <> "" Then

            state.RefreshToken = My.Settings.SavedAuth

            If (Client.RefreshToken(state)) Then
                Return state
            End If
        End If

        'Get the auth URL:
        state.Callback = New Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
        Dim authUri As Uri = Client.RequestUserAuthorization(state)

        'Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
        Process.Start(authUri.ToString())

        'wait until user has entered the code
        Dim authCode As String = InputBox("Authorisation code", "Authorisation Code", "")

        'Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
        RetVal = Client.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state)

        'store the refresh token
        Call StoreRefreshToken(state.RefreshToken)

        Return RetVal

    End Function

    Private Function LoadRefreshToken() As String

        Return My.Settings.SavedAuth

    End Function

    Private Sub StoreRefreshToken(ByVal Token As String)

        My.Settings("SavedAuth") = Token
        My.Settings.Save()

    End Sub

End Class
```